# How do I convert Decimals to Fractions with the custom code I have?

Tags: vba, reporting-services

I have created this custom code for a SSRS report to covert fraction to decimals and when I try to run the report I am the following error[SSRS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQyrN.png). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. The code is below

```
********Public Function Dec2Frac(ByVal decimalNumber As Decimal, ByVal den As Integer)
As String
Dim fracString As String
        Dim dp As Decimal = decimalNumber Mod 1 'determine decimal portion
        Dim wn As Integer = CInt(Fix(decimalNumber)) 'determine whole number
portion
        Dim num As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(dp * den + 0.5)) 'determine
numerator
        If num = 0 Then 'decimal rounds down to next whole number
            fracString = wn.ToString
        ElseIf num = den Then 'decimal rounds up to next whole number
            fracString = (wn + 1).ToString
        Else 'somewhere between
            Do Until num Mod 2 = 1
                num = CInt(num / 2)
                den = CInt(den / 2)
            Loop
            If wn > 0 Then
                fracString = wn.ToString & " " & num.ToString & "/" &
den.ToString
            Else
                fracString = num.ToString & "/" & den.ToString
            End If
        End If
        Return fracString 'return string
    End Function******
```

Comment: From the error message, I would assume that when you're calling `Dec2Frac`, you're only passing one parameter in, instead of the required two.

Comment: Still trying to get this working?  As I said the last time you posted a question about this code -- people will be more likely to want to help if you use SO as intended and mark correct answers, respond to questions for more details, and generally try to work with the people who you are asking for help.  No one here gets paid to help you and giving some reputation is the only benefit SO users get from helping.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but what do you mean when you say I am only passing one parameter. @Mistella

Comment: I can't see the code you are using to call this, so I'm only guessing based off the error message. Since there are two required parameters in the declaration, when this function is called in the code, it needs to be given two values -- one for each of the parameters. If you are attempting to give the function two variables, I would recommending using `Debug.Print` and the locals window to verify that both variables have been assigned values of the correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

Available from: [Microsoft developer network](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fef639c9-f400-4ddf-920e-7a29dc15966d/converting-decimals-to-fraction-in-ssrs-reporting-tool?forum=transactsql)
credit to: [Eric Liu001](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/eric%20liu001/?ws=usercard-mini)

```
> Public Function Dec2Frac(ByVal f As Double) As String

   Dim df As Double
   Dim lUpperPart As Long
   Dim lLowerPart As Long

   lUpperPart = 1
   lLowerPart = 1

   df = lUpperPart / lLowerPart
   While (df <> f)
      If (df < f) Then
         lUpperPart = lUpperPart + 1
      Else
         lLowerPart = lLowerPart + 1
         lUpperPart = f * lLowerPart
      End If
      df = lUpperPart / lLowerPart
   End While
Dec2Frac =Cstr(lUpperPart\lLowerPart) & " " & CStr(lUpperPart mod lLowerPart) & "/" & CStr(lLowerPart)

End Function
```